# Formula for residence time/turnover rate with unsteady state

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, volume, analyticity

I'm not sure this is the correct place to ask my question... but maybe someone could still help me.

I'm looking for a way to calculate the residence time/turnover rate.
I have the production and consumption rate (they are different, but stable over time). 
And I have the volume (resp. concentration) change over time.

How can I calculate how long a molucule stays in the pool?
Or how long it takes until the whole "population" of molecules is renewed?

I tried several approaches, but it seems I did not yet find the correct direction (?)

1) close the "inflow" and look how long it takes until the pool is emptied. Then open the inflow, close the outflow and calculate how long it takes to reach the start-concentration.
But the problem here is, that it does not take into consideration, that "new" and "old" molecules are mixing and the uptake-change is the same for the new and old molecules. Also it doesn't adress the problem of the changing volume and therefore changing probabilites of the uptake of the "old" molecules.

2) normal residence time. Not usable for me, since I have a different in-outflow and changing volume. I found something from a pulp fabric but this didn't take into consideration, that there is a free mixing of the molecules.

3) next possibility would be in a direction of the "Urn problem". But I do not know how to build it up around the circumstance that there isn't a steady number of balls in there and that I remove "red balls" while put "white ones" into it.

Can someone point me into the correct direction?